# How to rewrite file to file using bash?

Tags: bash, xamarin.forms, android-manifest, visual-studio-app-center

I create builds using AppCenter.ms. But My project has many CustomAndroidManifest.xml files. It places on UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/

AppCenter automatically increments version code. But AppCenter changes it in AndroidManifest.xml.

Task: I need to rewrite CustomAndroidManifest.xml to AndroidManifest.xml before AppCenter will change build number.

Why I have many CustomAndroidManifests... because My App has many Configurations.

I've created appcenter-post-clone.sh file and put it in Droid folder. Please look at the my  script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$APPCENTER_XAMARIN_CONFIGURATION" == "Conf1" ];
then
cp -R $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/Conf1AndroidManifest.xml/. $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml/
if [ "$APPCENTER_XAMARIN_CONFIGURATION" == "Conf2" ];
then
cp -R $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/Conf2AndroidManifest.xml/. $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml/
fi
```

Main Idea is change first file to second. Thank you.

EDIT! Problem is that CustomAndroidManifest.xml dos not rewrite to AndroidManifest.xml.

Question: How can I rewrite one file to second using bash?

Comment: `cat $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/Conf1AndroidManifest.xml > 
$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`
and 
`cat $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/Conf2AndroidManifest.xml > 
$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/UserApp/UserApp.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`
or this is more complex problem ? 
What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Which is the question? Which is the problem? Which is the code failing?

Comment: Yes. If I use appcenter-post-clone.sh  Conf1AndroidManifest.xml does not rewrite AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: are you sure the script is getting executed?